# how to request the image uploaded by the user in slim v2?

Tags: php, slim

```
$fname = $app->request->post('fname');
```

i want to create a variable $image of the image which has been uploaded by client and save it to a folder. **The rolution required is in Slim v2 not in Slim v3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slim 3 upload image to server path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324782/slim-3-upload-image-to-server-path)

Comment: please read carefully... **i need it in slim v2 not v3**

Comment: Right, sorry! It looks like [v2 has no upload form functionality](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1099) and they use `$_FILES` directly. So [standard PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.post-method.php) apply.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463008) has v2 answer with sample.